# Android - How to accommodate a thread executing in AsyncTask doInBackground method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, loopj

I am trying to query a web service using loopJ and during this operation I want to show the users a progress dialog.  When the operation is complete, I want the progress dialog to dismiss and start a new activity intent.

I know AsyncTask is the way to go.  On onPreExecute method I show the progress dialog.  On doInBackground I am performing the network operation.  And onPostExecute I am dismissing the dialog and starting a new activity intent.

My issue is doInBackground will perform loopJ networkcall asynchronously so onPostExecute will finish first before my network operation.  If you look at my logs it will show:

"Starting new activity!"
"Fetched category services!"

rather

"Fetched category services!"
"Starting new activity!"

How do I accommodate an asynchronous task running doInBackground?  Is there a way in onPostExecute to wait till my asynch loopJ operation is done?

```
public class FetchCategoriesServices extends AsyncTask<HITECategory, String, String>
{
    private Category userSelectedCategory;
    private ProgressDialog busyDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        busyDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SearchActivity.this, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.progressDialogTitle), 
                                         getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.progressDialogMessage));
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(HITECategory... params) 
    {
        userSelectedCategory = params[0];

        String requestCategoryServiceURL = BASE_URL + "GetServices?CategoryID=" + userSelectedCategory.categoryID + "&ResponseType=JSON";

        try 
        {
            Client.get(requestCategoryServiceURL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String jsonResponse)
                {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    CategoryServicesListResponse Response = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, CategoryServicesListResponse.class);

                    categoryServiceresults = Response.categoryServices;

                    Log.d(getString(R.string.DebugKey), "Fetched category services!");
                }
            });
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.d(getString(R.string.DebugKey), "Error connecting to service and fetching category services list");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String params)
    {
        busyDialog.dismiss();
        Log.d(getString(R.string.DebugKey), "Starting new activity!");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CategoriesSearchActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you don't need an `AsyncTask` at all: the loopJ request is already asynchronous and provides methods for when the work is about to be started and has finished. Just make sure you do any UI related calls on the UI thread (i.e. by posting it to a `Handler` that was created on the UI thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the code in `onPostExecute` into `onSuccess` method:

```
        Client.get(requestCategoryServiceURL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String jsonResponse)
            {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                CategoryServicesListResponse Response = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, CategoryServicesListResponse.class);

                categoryServiceresults = Response.categoryServices;

                Log.d(getString(R.string.DebugKey), "Fetched category services!");
                youractivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                           busyDialog.dismiss();
                           Log.d(getString(R.string.DebugKey), 
                                            "Starting new activity!");
                           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                CategoriesSearchActivity.class);
                           youractivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                     }
                 });
            }
        });
```

Comment: ha, I completely didn't think about that.  I was too busy taking account of onPostExecute.  Thanks for the answer!